# Button not being rendered

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a new dynamic button for every title by reading the contents of the json file stored in the local directory.

JSON File

```
[
    {
        "page" : "Page1" ,
        "imptopics":[
            {
                "title" : "Btn1",
                "url" : "https:link/"
            },
            {
                "title" : "Btn2",
                "url" : "http:link/"
            },
            {
                "title" : "Btn3",
                "url" :"http:link"
            },
            {
                "title" : "Btn4",
                "url" : "http:link"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my react component,
I am using fetch to read the contents of json file,

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'


function ImportantTopics() {
    const [data,setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = () =>{
        fetch('popularlinksdata.json'
        ,{
            headers :{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
            }
        }
        )
          .then(function(response){
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(myJson){
              console.log(myJson)
              setData(myJson)
          });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            {
                data && data.length > 0 && data.map((topic) => {
                    topic.imptopics.forEach(element => {
                        console.log(element.title);
                        <Button  className="sprtLinksButton">{element.title}</Button>      
                    })
                }) 
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImportantTopics;
```

But the button is not being rendered,
It is being displayed in the console.
What can I be missing?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, @triaton.

Comment: Worked fine perfectly, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON content is actually an array and we don't know how many elements there are. If you want to render all the `imtopics` appearing in the JSON content, you can merge the `imtopics` into one.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';


function ImportantTopics() {
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const getData = () => {
    fetch('popularlinksdata.json', {
      headers :{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(myJson) {
      const imptopics = myJson.reduce((merged, item) => [...merged, ...item.imptopics], []);
      // we will have all the imtopics merged into `imptopics`
      setData(imptopics);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
      {
        data && data.length > 0 && data.map((topic, index) => (<Button key={index} className="sprtLinksButton">{topic.title}</Button>))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImportantTopics;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an Element or an array of Element. You a re not returning anything here

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything whereas `map` returns an array. So you can either change the forEach to map or push the elements needs to be rendered to a variable and render that variable. I'd recommend the first option.
Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'


function ImportantTopics() {
    const [data,setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = () =>{
        fetch('popularlinksdata.json'
        ,{
            headers :{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
            }
        }
        )
          .then(function(response){
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(function(myJson){
              console.log(myJson)
              setData(myJson)
          });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
            {
                data && data.length > 0 && data.map((topic) => {
                    topic.imptopics.map((element, imdex) => (
                        <Button key={index} className="sprtLinksButton">{element.title}</Button>      
                    ))
                }) 
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImportantTopics;
```

There are two things to note here:

1. arrow function has implicit return, but when `{}` is used, you should use `return` as stated in the other answers.
2. when you render an element array, a unique `key` is required. I've given index as key in the example. If any unique identifier is available in your case, I'd recommend using that.